# Write to text file in IDE Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code and am using an online IDE from School of Haskell:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    h <- openFile "message.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn h "Greetings earthlings"
    hClose h
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Where is message.txt saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FP Complete's Haskell IDE doesn't let you browse the files you've created from code. But your program still worked!

```
import System.IO

main = do
    h <- openFile "message.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn h "Greetings earthlings"
    hClose h

    r <- readFile "message.txt"
    print r
```

You should see `"Greetings earthlings\n"` in the console, as expected.

Comment: Is `hFlush` needed? AFAIK the `hClose` call should also flush any pending i/o on the file.

Comment: Oops, that's my bad. I took it out.